# Logrotating postgres logs

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, postgresql, logrotate

My PostgreSQL log is writing as a single file. Its becoming bigger and bigger day by say as postgresql.log. I can see logging_collector is set as ON and log_rotation_age is also set to 1 day. Still its not rotating the logs.

I am ok to use the normal logrotate.conf within linux. But Im bit confused about the postrotate script which sends the HUP kill signal to the PID.

Please let me know the recommended way to configure logrotate for postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The logfilename option needs some parameter , for eg, 
 To keep 7 days of logs, one log file per day named server_log.Mon, server_log.Tue, etc, and automatically overwrite last week's log with this week's log, set log_filename to server_log.%a, log_truncate_on_rotation to on, and log_rotation_age to 1440.

This worked for me.